# Whisper - How to convent model.safetensors to .h5 format or pytorch_model.bin?

Tags: huggingface, openai-whisper

After i train the model, I only have these file.

[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PpxF.png_

However, i find that other people will get tf_model.h5 or pytorch_model.bin after train their model.

I found that .safetensors is the latest format of that. But i need the ggml format. SO i want to convert the format to ggml with Whisper.cpp

I have train my custom model of Whisper. from blow reference:
https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qdS5ioA0pXoDPYPnbOlrOsXMxK0OR5yO

and want to convert the format to ggml with Whisper.cpp
https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/tree/master/models